# What triggers GWT's validation? What happens when validation fails?

Tags: java, validation, gwt

I am puzzled with how GWT's validation works.  I have read this [GWT Page on Validation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideValidation.html), but I am still uncertain of the following things:

- When is validation performed?  On a getter/setter?  When the data model is sent from server -> client?  From client -> server?
- What happens when validation fails?  Is a runtime exception thrown?

Suppose I have the following class:

```
package com.sixtyfootersdude.gwt.model;

public class Dog implements Serializable {

    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    public Dog () {
    }

    public void setName (String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName (){
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

---

At what points can `myDog.name` be empty or null?  For example suppose that I create a new dog like this:

```
Dog myDog = new Dog();
// Presently, myDog.name is null.

myDog.setName("Santa");
// Validation should now pass, but I am not sure if it is invoked here.

myDog.setName(null);
// Validations should now fail, but I am not sure if it is invoked here.

// What would I need to do to trigger validation?  When would validation be invoked?
```

---

Additional info:

- GWT 2.5 and GWT 2.7

Answer (score 1):

You seemed to have missed a few steps from the document you linked - "Creating a Validator Factory" shows how to build the validator, and shortly after that shows how to ask the validator if a given object is actually valid. It would look something like this:

```
public final class SampleValidatorFactory extends AbstractGwtValidatorFactory {

  /**
   * Validator marker for the Validation Sample project. Only the classes and groups listed
   * in the {@link GwtValidation} annotation can be validated.
   */
  @GwtValidation(Dog.class)
  public interface GwtValidator extends Validator {
  }

  @Override
  public AbstractGwtValidator createValidator() {
    return GWT.create(GwtValidator.class);
  }
}
```

...

```
Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
Set<ConstraintViolation<Person>> violations = validator.validate(myDog);
//do something with those violations, if any
```

> When is validation performed? On a getter/setter? When the data model is sent from server -> client? From client -> server?

Unless every single setter (or for some reason getter) actually called the validator, that wouldn't happen, and wouldn't result in exceptions anyway, just a set of errors that might be empty.

As shown above, the validation happens when you invoke `validator.validate(myBean)`. The server can support this in a much more general way, and you always must have the server check the work and not trust the client (since JS runs in the user's browser, so they can modify it maliciously). As such, your server should also run these same validations (and possibly more) when it sees the data.

> What happens when validation fails? Is a runtime exception thrown?

The method `Validator.validate(bean, groups...)` returns a `java.util.Set` of `ConstraintViolation` objects, specific to your bean, which specify the path to each error, a message, and any other custom data provided by the validators. No exception is thrown, though you might create one (either checked or runtime) and throw it from within your code somewhere. You could consider building this functionality into whatever logic you use for each form, and have it invoked as "Save" is clicked, or every 100ms - whatever makes sense for your project. Likely the easiest way to handle issues is to use the provided paths to highlight errors in some way for the user. Consider using the Editor framework's `HasEditorErrors` interface to help in this highlighting.